# How to set article width in joomla?

Tags: joomla, article, css

I would like to set a max-width for articles in Joomla, so that they are easier to read on a wide screen.
So far all I have tried resulted in a change in width of the complete template, which I don´t want.

Where is the width of an article defined?

Help would be very much appreciated !

Comment: use css media queries. Inspect your page in a browser console to see what css rules apply to any element

Comment: Yes, tried this with firebug, but that only resulted in changing other elements ( slideshow) as well.

Comment: nobody can tell you what rules to change or add... it depends on the html structure and css of any given page

Comment: example: http://www.globalsolarportal.org/index.php/en/

I would like only the text arae to be smaller..

Comment: create a rule for class `article-intro`

Answer (score 0):

As long as you continue using the T3 Framework and the HTML tag *article* in the content, it would be safe to set the max-width like (e.g. 200px)

```
#t3-mainbody article {
     max-width: 200px;
}
```

Additionaly, if you want to access only the paragraphs of them, leaving *headers* out of the *max-width*

```
#t3-mainbody article p{
     max-width: 200px;
}
```